# "xxx at a piece" meaning the same score in a game?

Tags: phrase-request

I heard a commentator say something like “9 points at a piece” meaning the same score for each team in a game. Did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the word you heard was actually “apiece”. I’m not familiar with a usage that includes “at” beforehand, so I would interpret it as “9 points apiece.”

> **apiece** *adverb* \ə-ˈpēs\
>   : for or to each person or thing
>
> - His shoes weigh four pounds *apiece.*
> - when you figure that they usually sell for six dollars *apiece,* you're getting quite a bargain
>
> <sub>Source: [Merriam-Webster definition of “apiece”](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apiece)</sub>